# In struts 2.0.14 the component <s:reset> button is not working after submitting the page?

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2.0.14 for my application. I have a  button to clear the textboxes. I have a few boxes which are stateful and values are persistent after the form is submitted.

My problem is that when I press the button before submitting the form it clears all values from the textboxes. But when I submit the form and press reset again, the textboxes do not reset.

Comment: I don't quite get your scenario, please clarify.  So I gather one of two things is happening: Either 1) you submit and before the submit has been processed you want to push the reset button and have it work or 2) you submit a form which perhaps stays on the same page as its action and then you try to click the reset button and it does not work.

Comment: @demongolem HI i am also getting the same issue. if you got the solution then please provide me.. Thanks in Adv

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but: to "reset" the fields of an HTML form is not the same as to "clear" them, it just means to reset their values to their "default" values, those that were set (typically) in the `value="..."` attribute of the field tag.

Now, consider the typical server-side form validation workflow, when the user has entered some field values, submited the form, and get it back from the server with some errors marked (typically in Struts2, this corresponds to the `INPUT` result). Here, the new HTML page that is returned to the user will have its form fields filled with the previously submitted values. Now, from the client side perspective, those are the "default" values of the form: if you "reset" the form (perhaps after editing it), those are the values that will be restored.

Comment: Yes. This seems true. What else to use to reset the page? Making an action and clearing out all the fields in the Action class and throwing user back to the jsp is not a good idea in my opinion. Do you suggest any alternative?